# How do I move an existing model to a new association relationship in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

In the rails documentation, the example for associations assumes the model 'customers' has_many 'orders'.  The code to create this association would be:

```
@order = @customer.orders.create(order_date: Time.now)
```

...but this just shows how to create a **new** 'order' model and associate it with a 'customer' model.  What would the code be if I wanted to associate an **existing** order to a customer?

Answer (score 0):

Fire up rails console by typing `rails c` and change it manually :

```
@order = Order.where(price: 10)
@order.customer_id = some_id
```

That's what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few of ways to do this. All of them are documented [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html%23method-i-has_many).

One way is like this, which assumes `@customer` and `@order` are already initialized objects.

```
@customer.orders << @order
```